# will multiple weblogic managed nodes with same log4j result in file lock?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, weblogic

My production setup has 1 physical server with 2 weblogic managed nodes running and deployed with a package war file.

The package war file contains the log4j configuration file which specifies the log file to be written to /log/mypath/mylogfile.log.

Will multiple weblogic managed nodes attempting to read/write to the same log file result in file lock/IO issues?

Comment: Have you set up an async log4j appender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have issues that will prevent the logs from rolling. Adding the the server name as a variable name with alleviate this, but will give you two log files instead of one. The log path will look like this:

/log/mypath/mylogfile.${weblogic.Name}.log

Comment: But, If I am having the same war file and variables how would ${weblogic.Name} would help?

Comment: The variable name will cause each JVM to create and use its own log file. This removes the contention of two JVMs trying to use the same file.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if there is too much logging going on, such as using full debugging to troubleshoot a high volume production system, we can get stuck threads.  I have seen this happen with just one managed server, let alone with several.  It might depend on log4j version but it has been a periodic problem for us with high log levels.